# facing error while copying files from one directory to another

Tags: shell

i have a part of my code as

```
<part of code>
cd new_version
echo "Location of rpm: $loct"
cp -R ${loct} .
<remaining code>
```

and the value of the loct that i am passing here in my script is /auto/ipcbu-build/Published/TPL_LIBRARIES/
but when i am running this script it prints  "Location of rpm:" as blank
and no files are getting copied to the current directory 
what could be the issue?
but when i am printing $1 the location passed in the script is getting printed

Comment: see http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html and verify that the parameters and permissions are correct

Comment: You have to use `$1` instead of `$loct` for first argument.

Comment: @nav_jan but $loct and $1 have the same value right?

Comment: @priyanka that can only be confirmed by looking at the complete script.